# Android: Facebook Messenger Platform and Referral Links

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-messenger

Been playing with the new Messenger platform, was wondering if there's a way to add referral data to the Google's Play store when a user hits the "install" button.
Is there a kind of metadata i can pass ?

Here's a link to the new [Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/products/messenger)

Comment: What kind of metadata are you trying to send? the content?

Comment: That's exactly what i'm asking, what kind of metadata i should send.
Basically if the user on the other side hits install, what data would facebook send to google ? talking about utm_source utm_type utm_term etc.. do i have some metadata i could add to change those values